# How to sort a list of objects by a property

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-3.5

I've got this chunk of code:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Status");
        dt.Columns.Add("File");
        dt.Columns.Add("Revision");
        int i = 0;

        foreach (SvnStatusEventArgs status in statuses) // statuses is a Collection
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();

            switch (status.LocalContentStatus)
            { 
                case SvnStatus.NotVersioned:
                    dt.Rows[i]["Status"] = "Not Versioned";
                    break;
                default:
                    dt.Rows[i]["Status"] = status.LocalContentStatus.ToString();
                    break;
            }

            dt.Rows[i]["File"] = status.Path;

            foreach(SvnInfoEventArgs info in infos) //infos is a Collection
            {
                if (status.Path.Equals(info.Path))
                {
                    dt.Rows[i]["Revision"] = info.Revision;
                    break;
                }
            }

            i++;
        }
```

`statuses` and `infos` can have up to 20K rows each, however, so my nested foreach could take a long time.

I thought I could maybe speed this up if I converted these Collections to Lists and then try to Sort them both by `Path`.

Looking over the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) for the Sort method, I have no idea how I'd go about comparing the `Path` field from SvnStatusEventArgs[n] and SvnStatusEventArgs[n+1]. Then I also started to wonder, since I'd be iterating in their entirety over both of these groups of objects and sorting them anyways, would that really be any more efficient than my existing code? I suppose it would  be n*2 as opposed to n*n, right?

For what it's worth, the `Path` field I'm trying to sort by is just a string.

Comment: Like this? `foreach (SvnStatusEventArgs status in 
             statuses.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.LocalContentStatus))`

Comment: It should be noted that sorting will still be very inefficient on the speed of things.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel hmm, that seems to be exactly what I'd want... Except order by Path and not LocalContentStatus, but yea.

Comment: @PhilipGullick could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorting can be a long process, especially using strings in large data sets (past experience). If you think you have two strings: A = "ABCDEFGH", B = "ABCDEFGHI" as you can see, it won't find the difference until the end, and if you think of this in a large list it becomes worst. Order by IS slightly quicker with large data. So @JeroenVannevel would be a valid answer.

Comment: @PhilipGullick oh, that makes sense. Have some fairly lengthy strings as well, 100 characters or more, easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a `Dictionary<string, int>`(the key is the path and the value the revision).

```
Dictionary<string, int> pathRevisions = infos
    .GroupBy(info => info.Path)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First().Revision);
```

....
in the loop:

```
int revision;
if(pathRevisions.TryGetValue(status.Path, out revision))
    dt.Rows[i].SetField("Revision", revision);
```

Comment: Thanks. Frankly I don't know the various collections super well so I don't really understand why this is better, but I'll read the MSDN page about Dictionaries I guess. And just a quick note; Revision is actually a `long` so I changed that.

Comment: Its more efficient sice it does not need to loop it to find the object. This method approaches an O(1) operation which means it is doesn't matter how large it is.

Comment: oh, I see. So I can just totally scrap the nested foreach since it uniquely identifies each entry from the Path? That makes sense.

Comment: @sab669: Yes, you don't need the inner loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was fairly unclear but since you said in the comments this is what you meant

```
foreach (SvnStatusEventArgs status 
         in statuses
         .OrderBy(x => x.Path))
```

This is a very basic approach though. If you want a more optimal one you should use Tim Schmelter's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best would just be to make a dictionary on infos - with key as path. That would be the most efficient overall.